# Child node filtering when using TransformToTree

Tags: wpf, treeview, dynamic-data

Treeview example is [here](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/FlatStreamToHierarchy).

Filter was applied after seeing [this](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData/issues/215) comment.

```
var filter = SearchHints.WhenValueChanged(t => t.SearchText)
                        .Select(BuildFilter);

_cleanUp = employeeService.Employees.Connect()
                .TransformToTree(employee => employee.BossId, Observable.Return((Func<Node<EmployeeDto, int>, bool>) DefaultPredicate))
                .Filter(filter)
                .Transform(node => new EmployeeViewModel(node, SearchHints))
                .Bind(out _employeeViewModels)
                .Subscribe();
...

private Func<Node<EmployeeDto, int>, bool> BuildFilter(string searchText)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText)) return node => true;

    return node => node.Item.Name.Contains(searchText, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

But the parent does not match the condition of the filter.
So no child nodes matching the condition are visible in the TreeView.

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19144210/70210521-3f12d500-1776-11ea-9173-5e932c00583c.png

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19144210/70210530-4508b600-1776-11ea-87ea-8b869619f940.png

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `WhenAnyValue` instead of `WhenValueChanged`.

I don't know why, but WhenValueChanged causes to lot of issues.